# Safely re-installing a distro without losing data

Tags: system-installation

I'm currently running Debian(Wheezy) - recently wanted to set some file permissions to open using `chmod -R 777 *`. I know it's often frowned upon but it was just some code that I needed to view. However when doing it from terminal I took it for granted that I was in the right directory. Turns out I threw that command whilst in File System and therefore set ALL my system to open.

Apart from the obvious security flaw, it also caused bugs within the system, particularly using `su` or `sudo` won't work as the files permission in `/usr/` have changed.

---

I read it's simply better to re-install the system over again. I don't mind doing that, however I'd like to ask how may I do it without losing any of the files that I currently have in my harddrive?

Comment: That depends on how your hard drive is partitioned. Is your /home in a separate partition? Your / partition needs to be formatted so you can't keep your existing applications unless you have a fairly complex partitioning scheme. Keeping your music, photos etc should be easier but we need more details about what you want to keep and how your system is set up.

Comment: @terdon - No, everything is kept within a single partition. Since this seems like a fairly tedious thing to go through I think the smart thing would be to back everything that I need and simply clean and install the whole system again. However I wanted to know how to possibly go through this in a more professional way rather than just taking the easy way out

Comment: Ugh, next time, make sure you have at least /home on its own partition. That can make situations like this much easier. Anyway, I don't think you have much choice, just backup and reinstall.

Comment: @Juxhin you can still ON your system right and launch any program ?

Comment: @terdon - Yea that sounds like the way to go. Thanks alot terdon

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - The system itself is working fine. However I don't have permissions to sign in as root or use `sudo` since the file permissions required have been changed for all the system. Basically I accidentally set every file to permission 777

Comment: @Juxhin can you try launching a program(for example, unetbootin, software and updates) which asks for password on start and tell whether its opening or not ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - I had my Java IDE which I would try to run. When running as root it loads fine. When running as regular user it asks me for my license again. Therefore it cannot access the files it needs. I also tried loading root terminal(prompts user for password), after typing it I get the following - `Failed to communicate with gksu-run-helper.`

Comment: @Juxhin try to install timeshift after downloading it from this [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67740416/linux/timeshift-latest-amd64.run?dl=1). also try to make backup of your files and tell me whether it worked or not

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - Permission has been denied. Was not allowed to run the file. Should I simply back everything up and reinstall Debian?

Comment: come to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19232/discussion-between-juxhin-and-edward-torvalds